# Top Navigation Bar Drop down not working

Tags: master-page, navigation, dropdown, top-link-bar

OK so I have about 6 links on the top navigtion bar for my SharePoint site and there are subsites under each. Basically the structure is like this:

Top Link 1
  - Sub Link 1
     - Sub Sub Link 1
     - Sub Sub Link 2
  - Sub Link 1
.
.
.
And so on...

Now this all works fine with no issues BUT now I just tried creating another Sub Sub link under on of the Sub Links and it doesn't show up. Its the EXACT same setup as the ones that work but these don't want to show up. What could it be? Site settings -> Navigation is exactly the same as the ones that work and no changes to the masterpage have been made...why doesnt the second flyout menus show up?

In the quick launch menu it seems to work and both levels of the flyouts works just not on the top link bar, I am using Links to show the options for the top link bar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im taking a shot in the dark here but i think you need to set:

```
StaticDisplayLevels="X"
```

or

```
MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="X"
```

this is an example from msdn:

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu id="V4QuickLaunchMenu" runat="server" 
EnableViewState="false" DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap" 
UseSimpleRendering="true" UseSeparateCss="false" Orientation="Vertical"
StaticDisplayLevels="1" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1" 
SkipLinkText="" CssClass="s4-ql" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466994.aspx

hope this helps :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71912/discussion-on-answer-by-ali-jafer-top-navigation-bar-drop-down-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly be that you've added a custom 'subsites' heading to the menu; then, collected the subsites under that custom heading and indented them by using the 'Move Up' or 'Move Down' arrows.

If so, try to remove the indent so that the sites are flush to the left along with the heading. You'll probably see that the dropdown arrow and subsites now appear in the global menu.